# Writing Games for Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows

I have a year experience with XNA and some background in C++ and I'm really interested in making games for Windows 8 with the goal of selling them in the windows store in mind.  I've done a lot of googling and I have no idea what I should start with.  Should I use MonoGame, C++ with DirectX, or SharpDX?  Or have I missed another big one?  I'm just overwhelmed at the amount of choices there seems to be and which direction I should head.  I want to make the most logical choice for my skill level which basically means I would like something with a lot of documentation and examples.  Thanks!

Comment: This question is really too broad for stack overflow. The questions here should be ["practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face"](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) - it's better to ask questions here when you have tried something and gotten stuck.

Comment: If u have good experience in XNA, you can try to port your app using this
http://andrewrussell.net/exen/

Comment: There is also HTML5 as an alternative. For a guide, check out http://digitalerr0r.wordpress.com/2012/10/08/html5-game-starter-kit-for-windows-8/